# Submersion between smooth manifolds and horizontal vector fields

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, smooth-manifolds

The following proposition is Proposition 2.25 in John Lee's *Introduction to Riemannian Manifolds*.

**Proposition.** Let $N$ and $M$ be smooth manifolds, let $\pi:N\to M$ be a smooth submersion, and let $g$ be a Riemannian metric on $N$.

(a) Every smooth vector field $W$ on $N$ can be expressed uniquely in the form $W=W^H+W^V$ where $W^H$ is horizontal, $W^V$ is vertical, and both $W^H$ and $W^V$ are smooth.

(b) Every smooth vector field $X$ on $M$ has a unique smooth horizontal lift to $N$.

(c) For every $x\in N$ and $v\in H_x$, there is a vector field $X$ on $M$ whose horizontal lift $\tilde{X}$ satisfies $\tilde{X}_x=v$.

(a) is proved in the book, and the proofs of (b) and (c) are omitted. I tried to prove (b) as follows: Uniqueness is clear, so only need to check smoothness. It suffices to show that there is a (not necessarily horizontal) smooth lift $Y$ of $X$ (then the horizontal component of $Y$ is smooth, and is the horizontal lift of $X$). Using the fact that submersion is locally a projection, I've showed such $Y$ exists by locally lifting $X$ and using a partition of unity argument. Does my argument work? And I have no idea for part (c). Any hints?

Comment: For part (c), just define $w = \pi(v)$ which is tangent to $M$. Then extend it to a vector field on $M$, and use (b).

Comment: (too late for editing the above comment) Of course, I meant $w = \pi_*v (=\mathrm{d}\pi(x) v)$

Comment: @DIdier_ Thanks.